# Remove page editing by admins on a multi site environment

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I wish to block admins (multisite admins) to edit or publish any pages on their sites. I used the following function but for some reasons, it's not working. Can I get some suggestion as how I can achieve this?

```
function disable_page_editing() {
    $roles = array('administrator');
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $role =& get_role($role);

        $role->remove_cap('admin', 'edit_others_pages');
        $role->remove_cap('admin','edit_published_pages');
        $role->remove_cap('admin','publish_pages');
        $role->remove_cap('admin','delete_pages');
}
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'disable_page_editing');
```

Source: http://shinephp.com/delete-posts-and-pages-wordpress-user-capabilities-set/

Answer (score 0):

If you willing to go to plugin route, I use this free plugin and it has always worked for all cases I have tried even in multi-site environment.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Comment: Frankly speaking, I did use that plugin and it worked fine. However, why on earth it does not disable publishing/editing pages for admins on the sub-sites. I tried all mean, even removed all the admin privileges by unchecking all the settings (and applying to all sites) other than 'read' but still I could publish a page. Not sure where I went wrong there.

Comment: Hmm I have not tested this case, however you sure, you were not logged in as Super admin when you tested on sub-site?